# How to retrieve values from an int array?

Tags: java, arrays

Trying to revise my concepts for Java array and print after generating numbers between min and max value and trying to extract the numbers stored in the array however get it as zero however length still shows 10. I think the answer is once the array is defined we cannot manipulate it and might need to use ArrayList, can somebody confirm and shed some light on it

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // Define the array of numbers from 1 to 10
     
    int minInput = 0;
    int maxInput = 10;
    int[] newAr = null;

    for (int in = minInput; in < maxInput; in++) {

        // create a new array with numbers with max value
        newAr = new int[maxInput];

        // add + 1 values to the array
        newAr[in] = in;

        System.out.println("printint array" + newAr[in]);
    }

    System.out.println(newAr.length);

    // find values in array
    for (int i : newAr) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new array on each iteration of the first loop? That sounds very counterintuitive

Comment: Thats a good catch this should be outside the loop and it works

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
// Define the array of numbers from 1 to 10

int minInput = 0;
int maxInput = 10;
// create a new array with numbers with max value
int[] newAr = new int[maxInput];

for (int in = minInput; in < maxInput; in++) {
    // add + 1 values to the array
    newAr[in] = in;

    System.out.println("printint array " + newAr[in]);
}
```

The issue with the code from the question is next: inside for-loop you create a new array. Just move it before the loop.